# What is the compressive strength of carbon nanotube reinforced polymer?

Tags: materials, carbon-fiber

What is the range of compressive strength of carbon nanotube reinforced polymers?

Although CNT's themselves have phenomenal (oriented) compressive strength, and one can find references to that, CNRP's incorporate CNTs in the polymer matrix and polymers are not known for their compressive strength.

There is a lot of materials data on various carbon nanotube reinforced polymers but it all seems focused on applications where compressive strength isn't limiting.

Comment: One way of looking at the problem is to examine data from carbon-black filled elastomers (used in tires).  The fracture toughness of the material improves and that helps improve the compressive strength.  Longer CNT fibers will buckle in compression.

Comment: See "Properties of composites of carbon nanotube fibres" by Mora et al. Composites Science and Tech, 2009, 69(10), 1558-1563 and reference that cite that paper.